# Validation is not working in Textbox

Tags: wpf, validation

I have a TExtBox and have created a ValidationRule class from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43257/Simple-Validator-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundatio) and this is my xaml :

```
<TextBox Name="ctsTxt" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     local:SimpleValidator.ValidationType="{x:Type system:Double}"
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
                     Style="{StaticResource txtBoxStyle}" 
                     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2"                          
                     />
```

As per this and the validator class, the textbox sh accept only double input, but it accepts everything.

What's wrong in xamls that my validation is not happening at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it fire the error template?

Comment: @KDiTraglia, while debugging it does go thru OnValidationTypeChanged, but after wards, it never goes to OnValidationTypeChanged method nor any changed from Validation.ErrorTemplate or Style.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your Text Binding like this?

```
Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

Comment: Yet, nothing is happening. I just added ValidatedOnDataErrors, other all is the same.